# Install Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell Wyse 5070 thin client

Tags: system-installation, usb, ssd, iso

Can I use a USB adapter cable for M.2 SSD on my Windows 10 PC to flash Ubuntu ISO to the new M.2 SSD then just plug into 5070 motherboard? I recall doing this a few years ago but don't find this procedure on Ubuntu download instructions.

Thanks

Comment: Installing ISO to a drive, usually a smaller flash drive, totally erases the drive. You would not want to do that to a larger SSD unless you had nothing else on it. And that is the installer. If you have lots of RAM, you can add the toram parameter so when booting ISO you have it all in RAM, and then can install to same drive. But if any issues, you do not have the live installer to make repairs. I now use SSD in USB3 adapter, but have grub use loop mount to boot ISOs with full install & data also on SSD.

Comment: Very kind of you to respond. Unfortunately, I understand very little of what you said as I am very inexperienced with Ubuntu. So now I will prepare a USB drive as described on the Ubuntu website and try that. Thank you